# Eclipse desktop shortcut keeps disappearing at every startup?

Tags: launcher, eclipse, shortcuts

Every time I start up my Ubuntu 15.10 desktop the Eclipse shortcut on the desktop (and on the launcher) disappears.

I tried to create the shortcut both using "right click -> create shortcut" and manually by creating a .desktop file and enabling the executable file option but I got the same result: after a reboot the link is missing. While this is not a problem for starting Eclipse, it is however rather annoying. How can I fix this?

Comment: Silly question, but do other files, created on your desktop remain? If so, what is the name of the `.desktop` file? Not sure if I can help in any way, but we might find a clue.

Comment: Not silly at all. Yes all the other files do remain. I have a couple of text file in the desktop and a folder and they're still there, although I can't say if changes to those file are kept (I could verify this at the next reboot if it may help). The name of the desktop file was Eclipse.desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the desktop file using the following,

```
sudo desktop-file-install /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

Create a link file using the below command to open eclipse in command mode.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/
```

That’s it , Now you can launch eclipse.